# Microsoft Access database table with percentage sum

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Hi I have a total sum let say $100 and I want a new column to return 20% of (user input)  which let say for example is $100 20% of $100 is $20 (so the table displays $20) how would I do that in a data table with expression builder?
Help would be much appreciated! Thanks

(Sorry the first time I asked this I was a little to broad)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to do this in Excel?  It has built-in functions and other tools specifically meant for financial analysis of any level

Comment: We use excel now but we want to automate some things that now take manual input like a profit and loss statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expression:

```
=0.2*[TotalSum]
```

Then apply the format: *Currency*

But do that either in a *query* or as the *ControlSource for a textbox* in your form, not in the table; tables are not for this.

Comment: Thanks for you answer I wasn’t clear on what I want to achieve sorry about that, I wanted the column to display 20% of whatever the user inputs like if the user inputs the value $100 the column displays $20

Comment: The, I guess, all you need is a textbox (bound to that expression) on your form.

Comment: Yours is the correct answer. Just replace the format type with Currency

Comment: @dbmitch: Right, thanks. It was a left-over from the 20%. Corrected,

Answer (score 0):

if your column in database is value1 for ex. than create your sql query like this

```
 Format((20*100)/[value1],"Standard") AS 20Percent
```

in Expression builder like this

```
20Percent: Format((20*100)/[value1];"Standard")
```

Replace value1 with your column name.

Comment: This is great but would this work if the sum ($100) was user imputed like 20% of (user input)

Comment: i didn't get you. you have column which contain a value of 100 like '$100' or just a numeric value?

Comment: I want a new column to return 20% of the (user input) which let’s say is $100 the column displays $20

Comment: Sorry I haven’t been clear on what I want to achieve